# Given a Debian-based OS, If the OS image becomes corrupted, how can it reinstall over the network remotely

Tags: linux, debian, installation, remote-access

We have a raspberry pi system that needs to be able to remotely re-image itself, if the image becomes corrupted or on demand. How do I go about doing this?

Also, how do I setup a pi that wasn't originally configured to do this?

The OS I am using is Raspbin, also device is 4 hours drive away. So physically changing the SD card is a no go.

Comment: AFAIK you can't netboot over wifi.  With wireless ruled out things are very complicated.  If you skip the wireless requirement, then you just build a netboot setup that does whatever you require to install your image.  There are tons of docs/books on netboot installs and such.  I am sure you can research that on your own.

Comment: Ok, I was just told it is also hooked via Ethernet connection. How can I do this. We like an exact image to be installed of our sd card to be installed..

Comment: Please don't ask the same question twice. If you need to update your question, or if it isn't getting attention, please edit it instead; this will bump the post to the top of the front page.

Comment: Would running the OS off a USB key be an option? Its significantly more robust. The RPI dosen't really have any out of band management tools.

Answer (score 0):

While this is not impossible i'd class trying to reimage a device remotely as a high risk option, particually if it wasn't originally set up for such reimaging and particuallly if you don't have a remote serial console and remote power control

is there really noone you can post a SD card to and have them swap it? what ifs your plan B if the remote reimage fails? is the corruption really so bad it can't be fixed in place?

If you have spare unpartitioned space at the end of the drive then you could create a new partition there, copy a partition image (not a disk image) to it and then modify the files on the boot partition to boot it.

If you don't have spare unpartitioned space you would have to copy some kind of recovery environment that can by loaded off the boot partition run out of ram only to the SD card. Said recovery environment would have to be able to bring up the network and let you ssh in. Once you were running that environment you could then reimage the SD card. I'm not sure if such environments are available pre-canned or not but i'm sure it would be possible to put one together with buildroot or a similar tool.

Whatever you do test it on a local Pi first to minimise the risk.